# Effect on current draw and voltage when splitting a signal to many places

Tags: voltage, current

I have tried to Google answers to this already, but every search I make comes up with answers to other questions. That said, I'm happy to just be given links if there are already legit answers out there.

So I'm still quite new to electronics. And I have a part of a project in mind that will involve sending an AC audio signals from. An output jack to a great many input jacks. All unbalanced and working between +/- 5V range. If it helps clarify the situation, I'm talking about inputs and outputs on modular synth systems. I wish to preserve the voltage as best I can, and I obviously don't want to blow anything up. So my questions are as follows:

What kind of voltage drop (if any) am I likely to experience per split (or more importantly, how many splits could I get away with before the voltage dropped significantly).

Will each extra input that I send the signal to cause extra current to flow through the output, or will the current just split between each input?

Are there any other things I'll need to consider to avoid any catastrophes?

Cheers in advance for any advice, pete

Sorry for the crap tags, not sure what specifically to tag this with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of voltage drop (if any) am I likely to experience per split

That depends on the input impedance of each individual input, and the output impedance of the output.

If the output impedance is low and all the input impedances are high, you will not see significant voltage drop.

> (or more importantly, how many splits could I get away with before the voltage dropped significantly).

The lower the output impedance, the more splits you can get away with. The higher the combined input impedances, the more splits you can get away with.

> Will each extra input that I send the signal to cause extra current to flow through the output, or will the current just split between each input?

Yes and yes. Strike the "or".

> Are there any other things I'll need to consider to avoid any catastrophes?

Don't draw too much current, in other words make sure the input impedances are high enough for the output.

Google Ohm's law and Kirchhoff's laws. Memorize the former. Understand the latter.

Get acquainted with electronics and safety. Electricity can kill or start fires, so make sure to inform yourself, so that you're able to make judgements on whether a certain circuit is potentially dangerous or not, how to stay safe, and how to design stuff that is safe.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. To clarify regarding the current, more connections would see a drop in draw, but combined the total draw will increase per connection? I'm guessing (and this definitely surely isn't an educated guess) that this is something to do with resistance, and is one of the times ohms law will help me figure it out?

Comment: I feel like I should mark this as correct because you covered every point, but I don't know enough to know that you're right, haha! That's tricky. I'm sufe you are correct though. If no one counters this by tomorrow I'll mark as correct. Then I'm gonna get on your suggested reading, get out my volt meter and try to set up some test circuits to see for sure what happens...

Comment: You can view your input jacks as parallel resistors. Here is a tutorial about parallel resistors: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_4.html The more connections, the larger the total current draw from the loads, and as a consequence, the larger the voltage drop from the output.

Comment: Cheers once again! This is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Dampmaskin's answer which is great.

> Are there any other things I'll need to consider..

The more "things" and cables you attach to your output, the more opportunities noise and oscillation has to enter your system.

You need to be aware of the effects of ground loops and feedback loops. How you physically connect things together can often be more critical than how many.

Comment: Ok. Cool cheers, that's helpful info. What kind of protection can I utilise for an AC signal? The only protection I know about so far is pull up and pull down resistors, and they don't feel like they'd be appropriate here